# Converting python/numpy code into pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I've written some code that uses numpy's array broadcasting logic and need to convert it to pseudocode. Basically, $w\in R^{T}$ and $\beta\in R^{T \times M}$. If you have the following code using numpy arrays:

```
T = 100
M = 10
w = np.ones(T) / T
b = np.ones((T, M))
x = (w * b).sum(axis=0)
```

Numpy will automatically broadcast `w` to the correct axis of `b` and `x` becomes the weighted average of `b` along `axis=1`. How do I convert something like this into pseudocode?

Comment: In my eyes, terse Python code is close to pseudocode for showing little "syntactic acid". Code comments aside, you could start replacing assignment operators (`=` to ←). In machine translating between programming languages, a problem noted just after proposing a large *semantic gap* to be difficult was the possibility of a *semantic clash*: I'd recommend starting with aloft prose how the task at hand is accomplished. The problem with NumPy (SciPy in general) is introducing a "vocabulary" difficult to assume known - just as the corresponding "mathematical notation" beyond basic operations.

Comment: To begin with, your code doesn't compile for me. `w * b` throws `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (100,10)`. Regarding the pseudocode: I would write everything explicitly, with loops. E.g. "**for** $i = 1 \ldots T$ **do** $w_i \gets \frac 1T$". The last line can be written as "**for** $i = 1\ldots M$ **do** $x_i \gets \sum_{j=1}^T w_j \cdot b_{ji}$" (or whatever that line should do).

Comment: There is no standard for pseudocode. Pseudocode should be understandable for somebody who doesn't know anything about python or numpy.

Comment: For example, I am not familiar with the `np.ones` function, and there is no reason I should be in order to understand your algorithm. Similarly, it's not clear what `w * b` does, and what does it mean to sum along `axis=0`. You can probably express the `x = ...` statement in the form $x_i = \cdots$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments all. I guess you're right I shouldn't try and rely on numpy's syntactic sugar (or acid) and spell it out properly. Thanks again